# Google API request every 30 seconds

Tags: php, caching, google-api-php-client

I'm using Live Reporting Google APIs to retrieve active users and display the data inside a mobile application. On my application I'd like to make a HTTP request to a PHP script on my server which is supposed to return the result. 
However I read on Google docs that it's better not to request data using APIs more often than 30 seconds.
I prefer not to use a heavy way such as a cron job that stores the value inside my database. So I'd like to know if there's a way to cache the content of my PHP scrpit na dmake it perform an API request only when the cache expires.
Is there any similar method to do that?

Comment: if you're not performing the call to the API on a page request, then you're going to have to use CRON - there's no way (as far as I know) to trigger an action on an event like cached data expiring.

Comment: @Kryten yes, the API call should be performed on page request but only if the cache is more than 30 seconds old

Comment: Then it should be simple enough to check the age of the cache on each page request & decide whether you want to make an API call. Use the file system or a database to save the date/time of the last API call and check it each time a page loads - overhead shouldn't be much if you're just grabbing timestamp value.

Comment: @Kryten the point is that I don't want to create neither a value nor a database field to store just this

Comment: If you want to do it on a per-user basis, you could store the value in a cookie, but then it's likely you'll wind up making API calls more frequently than every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be implementing a very simple cache by yourself.

```
$googleApiRequestUrlWithParameter; //This is the full url of you request
$googleApiResponse = NULL; //This is the response by the API

//checking if the response is present in our cache
$cacheResponse = $datacache[$googleApiRequestUrlWithParameter];
if(isset($cacheResponse)) {
  //check $cacheResponse[0] for find out the age of the cached data (30s or whatever you like
  if(mktime() - $cacheResponse[0] < 30) {
    //if the timing is good
    $googleApiResponse = $cacheResponse[1];
  } else {
    //otherwise remove it from your "cache"
    unset($datacache[$googleApiRequestUrlWithParameter]);
  }
}

//if you do no have the response
if(!isset($googleApiResponse)) {
   //make the call to google api and put the response in $googleApiResponse then
   $datacache[] = array($googleApiRequestUrlWithParameter => array(mktime(), $googleApiResponse)
}
```

If you data are related to the user session, you could store $datacahe into $_SESSION
http://www.php.net/manual/it/reserved.variables.session.php

ortherwise define $datacache = array(); as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of way of caching things in PHP, the simple/historic way to manage cache in PHP is with APC http://www.php.net/manual/book.apc.php

Maybe I do not understard correctly your question.

Comment: I'm going to write some code with this, thank you in the meantime

Comment: On my shared hosting, APC is not available